# How to make specific words bold in a Text Box in Microsoft Word using C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have an application that will print a .docx file, which has a Text Box shape with text. In it, there are certain words that need to be bold.

For example, a part of the text is "...representando a empresa M&A, o presente..." and only "M&A" needs to be bold.

However, I don't know for sure how I can do this. I've searched in SO, as well as other sites like MSDN and such, but none provide the solution. Could anyone help me?

EDIT: I'm using Interop to achieve this. The code I've done so far is as follows:

```
// opens word app
wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
wordApp.Visible = false;

// print dialog for settings input
PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
if (pd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    wordApp.ActivePrinter = pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;

    // opens the document
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(filePath);

    // iterates through each shape in the file
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shape in doc.Shapes)
    {
        string shapeName = shape.Name;

        // checks whether the shape is a Text Box
        if (shapeName.StartsWith("Text Box"))
        {
            string shapeText = shape.TextFrame.ContainingRange.Text;

            // checks whether the shape is the one I want to modify 
            // side note: there are more shapes in the file, so I specify it
            if (shapeText.StartsWith("Concedemos"))
            {
                // erases the text, and sets it to a string
                shape.TextFrame.ContainingRange.Text = "";
                shape.TextFrame.ContainingRange.Text = "textSample";
            }
        }
    }

    // prints the file
    wordApp.ActiveDocument.PrintOut();
}

// quits the app
wordApp.Quit();
wordApp = null;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code extract below demonstrates how to loop through all Shapes in a Word document, check whether it's a text box (drawing element) that begins with the desired string, then search the text box for the term to be bolded and bold it.

1. It's possible to check the `Shape.Type` to determine whether or not it's a text box. The `Shape.Type` is an *Office* Enum (since the `Shape` object is common to many Office applications). So `if (shapeType == Office.MsoShapeType.msoTextBox)`
2. To pick out text and format it, most often Word's `Range.Find` functionality is the best approach. It enables to find and replace formatting, as well as string values. (Tip: When embarking on a project that requires this kind of thing it's often a good idea to test in the dialog box (Ctrl+H) in the Word UI to figure out the right combination of parameters.)
3. To understand what all the parameters of `Find.Execute` are for, consult the Help or look at Intellisense (or a combination of the two).

For this example, it's important to note that, in order to format the target text no `Replacement.Text` is specified.

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shape in doc.Shapes)
{
    Office.MsoShapeType shapeType = shape.Type;

    // checks whether the shape is a Text Box
    if (shapeType == Office.MsoShapeType.msoTextBox)
    {
        // checks whether the shape is the one I want to modify 
        // side note: there are more shapes in the file, so I specify it
        if (shapeText.StartsWith("Concedemos"))
        {
            string textToBold = "M&A";
            Word.Range rngTextBox = shape.TextFrame.TextRange;
            Word.Find rngFind = rngTextBox.Find;
            rngFind.Text = textToBold;
            rngFind.Replacement.Font.Bold = -1;
            object oFindStop = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop;
            object oTrue = true;
            object oReplaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
            object missing = System.Type.Missing;
            rngFind.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref oFindStop, ref oTrue, ref missing, ref oReplaceAll,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        }
    }
```